# Filter a group in mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-except

I have following sample data from a table

```
Id      Dsc
500001  INSURED
500001  THIRD PARTY
500001  THIRD PARTY
500001  THIRD PARTY
500002  INSURED
500002  THIRD PARTY
500003  INSURED
500004  BROKER
500005  CLAIMANT
```

I wish to extract those Ids for which Dsc is neither 'Insured' nor 'Broker'. Since both columns have repetitive data, I have devised following query for this..

```
Select Id from table1 where Dsc not in ('Insured', 'Broker')
Except
Select Id from table1 where Dsc in ('Insured', 'Broker')
```

Is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: It is an MSSQL database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM table1 GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Dsc='Insured' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN Dsc='Broker' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query as:

```
SELECT Id FROM (
SELECT Id , SUM(CASE WHEN Dsc IN ('INSURED','BROKER') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Condition
FROM @Test
GROUP BY Id
) T 
WHERE Condition = 0
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80b15/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery for the same:

```
Select id,dsc from (select id,dsc from table1 group by id, dsc) 
where dsc not in('Insured', 'Broker')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to stop repeating column

```
Select distinct *from table1
```